# Is there a way to change the formatting (font, color, etc.) of the interactive elements for "bind"?

Tags: vega-lite

Using the `bind` property in vega-lite will show an interactive element (e.g., a slider, dropdown, radio, etc.). For example, in https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bind.html, there is a sample showing [the name of the bound parameter, org_Origin, and the dropdown values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEs3Z.png) in the default font. Is there any way to change this, e.g., set the color of the name "org_Origin" to white?

I played around with the `config` definition for `selection`, as well as potential other options that it could possibly inherit from (`title`, `header`, `legend`), but was unable to find anything that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to apply a css style or this via deneb?

[image]

Via css you could add the following for example:

(Online css: **.example .vega-bind select**)

```
.vega-bind select {
    max-width: 180px;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    color: blue !important;
    background-color: aliceblue !important;
    border-color: silver;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    padding: 4px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not sure this is possible in Deneb (it does not seem to have an option to inject css styles), but this is a great option if I can host the visualization elsewhere.